# Syntax highlighting for fish script not working

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, plugin-vundle

I have both `Vim version 8.1.1550` and `NVIM v0.4.3` on MacOS 10.14.6

I wrote the following lines in my `.vimrc` file as recommended [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932906/syntax-coloring-with-vim-and-fish-shell)

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'dag/vim-fish'

filetype plugin indent on    " required
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
```

As indicated [here](https://github.com/dag/vim-fish), I also created a `~/.vim/ftplugin/fish.vim` file and inserted the following in it:

```
" Set up :make to use fish for syntax checking.
compiler fish

" Set this to have long lines wrap inside comments.
setlocal textwidth=79

" Enable folding of block structures in fish.
setlocal foldmethod=expr
```

However I don't have highlighting for the following `fish_prompt.fish` file when opening it with vim

```
function fish_prompt
    set_color $fish_color_cwd
    echo ' [' (prompt_pwd) ' ] > '
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vundle configuration looks incorrect. You should call `vundle#begin()` at the start, before the `Bundle` commands. And you should call `vundle#end()` at the end of that section, before you re-enable filetype detection and plug-ins.

(The `vundle#rc()` function is an old way to initialize Vundle, it's deprecated now in favor of `vundle#begin()`.)

See the [Vundle Getting Started page](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start) for more details.

You probably also need to have `syntax enable` somewhere in your vimrc (not sure if it's there, only not showing in your small snippet.)

You should also use the canonical and more modern `'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'` location for Vundle itself. (You might need to reinstall it into that location, see the first steps in the Getting Started guide for instructions on that.)

I also switched the plug-in declarations to use the more modern `Plugin` instead of the older `Bundle`. (Vundle went through a few iterations of renaming things...)

Putting it all together:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'dag/vim-fish'

call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on    " required
syntax enable
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey
```

Hopefully straightening up your Vundle setup will get your fish syntax highlighting working as expected.

---

Personally, I'd actually recommend that you consider migrating from Vundle to [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), which is a much more modern take on a plug-in manager that is still similar to Vundle (such that users of Vundle will see a familiar environment in vim-plug.) You could say vim-plug is in a way a *successor* to Vundle in that sense.

You can simply [install](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md#installation) vim-plug with a simple shell command:

```
$ curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

After installing it, update your vimrc to the following configuration:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'dag/vim-fish'

call plug#end()

filetype plugin indent on  " optional!
syntax enable
highlight LineNr ctermfg=grey
```

That's all! No messing with `rtp` or having to set `filetype off` and back `on` in the right order and locations...

Once you start Vim with this configuration, simply run `:PlugInstall` to have your plug-ins installed by vim-plug. (Similar to how you would have used `:VundleInstall` or `:PluginInstall` on Vundle.)

See vim-plug's [documentation](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md) for more. In particular, you might want to take a look at this section on [migrating from other plug-in managers, Vundle in particular](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tips#migrating-from-other-plugin-managers).

Comment: Brilliant extensive answer. Many thanks @filbranden

Comment: @ecjb I'm glad it helped! Let me know if everything worked as expected or if anything might need adjusting.

Comment: it worked perfectly @filbranden